# Ayuda con expresion regular

Tags: r, regex

He intentado, sin éxito, crear una expresión regular que me permita diferenciar valores de un vector en R que tienen el siguiente formato

```
"sb183107"
"sb183108"
"sb183124"
"3989-15"
"761-16"
"3554-15"
```

He intentado con `[^\\d-]`, `[^sb][^\\d]`, `[^sb]` y `sb\\d+` pero no distingue entre los casos.

Se trata de diferenciar entre los elementos que comienzan con sb y los que comienzan con números. Ej. ejecutando `sum(grepl('[^\\d-]', vector))` donde `vector <- c("sb183107", "sb183108", "sb183124", "3989-15", "761-16", "3554-15")` se obtiene `> [1] 6` cuando debería obtener solo la suma de los elementos que NO comienzan con números

¿Alguna sugerencia, por favor?

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. ¿Entre qué casos debe distinguir? No me queda claro.

Comment: Por favor, especifica los criterios para que una búsqueda coincida. Escribe una entrada de datos y después una salida especificando qué debe encontrarse y qué no

Comment: Tal vez el problema no este en la expresión regular sino en lo que estás haciendo en R, edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que estás intentando ejecutar y define cuales son los casos que deseas detectar ya que no queda claro en tu pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Se trata de diferenciar entre los elementos que comienzan con sb y los que comienzan con números.    
Ej. ejecutando `sum(grepl('[^\\d-]', vector))` donde `vector <- c("sb183107", "sb183108", "sb183124", "3989-15", "761-16", "3554-15")` se obtiene     
`> [1] 6`    
cuando debería obtener solo la suma de los elementos que NO comienzan con números.

Comment: Creo que la correcta expresión regular de tu enunciado "elementos que NO comienzan con números",  sería `^\\d`

Answer (score 0):

Para encontrar cadenas que empiezan por número:

```
^[0-9]
```

Para encontrar cadenas que **no** empiezan por número:

```
^[^0-9]
```

Para encontrar cadenas que **no** empiecen por `sb` (no implica que empiecen por número, podrían empezar por otras letras o símbolos)

```
^(?:s[^b]|[^s])
```